# DataGrid View Multicolored Cell Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was looking to see if it was possible to create multicolored cell text in an asp.net DataGrid View. The project that I'm working on contains a cell that has info related to the status of a unit which has the values of Unit1--DP, Unit2--ER, Unit3--ON and a couple others and I want to chance the color of each based on if it says AV, DP, ER, or ON. The ideal would be to color AV as Green, DP as Orange, ER as Yellow, and ON as Red.

Any information on how to do this would be helpful as there isn't much information as to if this is possible currently available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for a listview, Gridview, Repeater, and datalist?

The place for doing formating of the data (or grid) display is the DataBound event. (or ItemDataBound event).

This lets you see/grab/use/change/format the one row of data for each "repeated" item.

So, if I have a list of hotels, and say for a given city, I could color it blue like this:

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) |
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) {

            TextBox txtCity = e.Item.FindControl("City") as TextBox;
            if (txtCity.Text == "Edmonton")
            {
                // set background as blue
                txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, in your case, you could grab that control (find control), and then based on the text that follows the --, then you could color/set the background of that given control.

So, something close to this :

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) |
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) {

            TextBox txtCity = e.Item.FindControl("City") as TextBox;

            
            string[] strSufix = txtCity.Text.Split(new string[] { "--" },StringSplitOptions.None);

            if (strSufix[1] == "AV")
                txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;

            if (strSufix[1] == "DP")
                txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

            if (strSufix[1] == "ER")
                txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

            if (strSufix[1] == "ON")
                txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }
    }
```

## Edit: So user has gridview, and multiple items per cell.

So, say this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"  HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"   HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"  HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="270" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Test" HeaderText="Test" ItemStyle-Width="270" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, and our code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

so, as suggested, we add/use the Row data bound for such formatting.

So, we can use some code say like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // format 5th cell (cell 4)

            string celltext = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
            string OcellText = celltext;  // save orginal fomat (with spaces)
            if (celltext.Contains("--"))
            {
                celltext = celltext.Replace(" ", ""); // trim blanks
                string[] Tokens = celltext.Split(',');
                foreach (string OneThing in Tokens)
                {
                    if (OneThing.Contains("--"))
                    {
                        string[] sufux = OneThing.Split(new string[] { "--" },StringSplitOptions.None);
                        if (sufux[1] == "AV")
                            OcellText = MyFormat(OcellText, OneThing, "LightGreen");

                        if (sufux[1] == "ON")
                            OcellText = MyFormat(OcellText, OneThing, "Red");
                    }
                }

                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = OcellText;
            }
        }
    }

    string MyFormat(string Source, string sFind, string MyColor)
    {

        string sHTML  = @"<span style=background-color:" + MyColor + ">" + sFind + "</span>";

        string MyResult = Source.Replace(sFind, sHTML);

        return MyResult;
    }
```

Now, when we run this, we get this:

[image]

Comment: I'm using a GridView to show the data. I already have something like that for some of my code already. The problem is that the cell looks like " Unit1--AV, Unit2--ON, etc.. ". So I have to be able to color code them within the single cell. They can't be split into individual rows for each unit because each row is a dispatched call.

Comment: Well you do want to be clear what control you using here (you stated datalist, so I did a datalist example - might be a week or two before I can come back and post a gv example). But, the above code would be near 100% the same for the gv. It not clear if you using cells (datafield), or you using templated controls. but, setting background color of a cell, or a control (templated) in the gridview will work identical to above. I used split command to get and grab the sufix after "--" to get the code ON, AV etc. So, yes above will color code a single cell

Comment: Or are you saying that one cell will have multiple values? (a mount Everest of a different question here). but, yes, you would need 2 splits, one to get each value - separated by the ",", and then the above split code. If one cell has multiple values, then what color do you want the one cell to become when it has more then one value in that cell?

Comment: The above question did state DataGrid and not DataList so that is why I was confused. What I'm trying to figure is that I have a DataGrid and each row has a cell that contains the values " Unit1--AV, Unit2--ON " all in one cell. Within the cell, I was trying to figure out if I can color the characters AV and ON to designated colors within the one cell. Right now I am using datafields and I am not familiar with templated controls.

Comment: well, now you stating data grid, and not gridview? That's ok (they all are very similar, so listView, GridView, DataGrid, DataList are similar in how they operate). It does help however for me to post code for a given control. So, each cell has multiple values, and you only want to highlight JUST the AV, ON part with a color. Hum, yes, that should be possible - but certainly more challenging since we will have multiple colors in one cell.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. In my asp.net site I am using a GridView to display the data. I'm trying to figure out how to highlight different parts of the text in the single cell since I can't split the text into multiple rows. I haven't been successful in finding anything that I can try so far.

Comment: Ok, see my code edit. I use a grid view, look for each "token" value, and if a match, then we color it a given color.